# isgl3d sphere not rendered completely

Tags: isgl3d

Trying to render a sphere using isgl3d. The problem is that only say 75% of the sphere is being rendered.

Here's the code:

```
[self.camera setPosition:iv3(0, 3, 7)];
_container = [self.scene createNode];

Isgl3dTextureMaterial * ballMaterial = [Isgl3dTextureMaterial materialWithTextureFile:@"balltext.jpg" shininess:0.7 precision:Isgl3dTexturePrecisionLow repeatX:YES repeatY:YES];

_sphere = [Isgl3dSphere meshWithGeometry:1 longs:40 lats:40];
node = [ _container createNodeWithMesh:_sphere andMaterial:ballMaterial];
[self.scene addChild:node];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the image size. I think it should be `32x32`, `64X64`, `128x128` or `256x256`. By changing image size you may be able to solve the issue.